# How come the dreams are shared correctly among different participants?

Tags: plot-explanation, inception

Please read the question before marking it as duplicate. This question maybe identical to the one below but they ask different concepts:

> [How does the dream sharing actually work?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2034/how-does-the-dream-sharing-actually-work)

So my question is how are the dreams shared correctly among the individuals? I've watched the movie twice but the only thing connected to all the dreamers are the conduits used to inject sedatives to the subjects of the dream. It hasn't been explained how the dream sharing actually work. Is it some kind of a telepathic practice?